# Local analysis (Pseudo relevance feedback )

Tags: information-retrieval

While studying relevance feedback(Pseudo relevance feedback), I have learn that the model can go horribly wrong for some queries. Can anyone give reasons why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is also called **query drift**: if the top-k retrieved documents are all (or mostly) about a particular sub-topic, the importance of such sub-topic is boosted by the feedback mechanism.

A textbook example is with a query about "copper mines": if most of the retrieved documents are about "copper mines in Chile", the feedback process will *drift* the results towards documents on Chile.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you have any idea for this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91557/rocchio-algorithm-relevance-feedback

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687072/rocchio-algorithm-relevance-feedback?rq=1